# Nested div in p:dialog

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am going to access `dialogForm`, Here is the code:

```
<div id="leftDiv">
  <div id="dialogDiv">
    <p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="dlg1">
        <h:form id="dialogForm">
           <h:panelGrid columns="3">
               // my components
           </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
   </div>
</div>
```

I try:

```css
#leftDiv #dialogDiv #dialogForm{
    background-color: red;
}
```

But not worked.

Comment: I have ran this code and it appears to work. Are you using an external stylesheet? If so, make sure you have the correct directory.

Comment: @TommyJinks Yes, But other stataments in external stylesheet works correctly!

Comment: Why do you put a dialog in a div and want to use that nesting to influence the dialog? Or in other words, what are you trying to achieve. You might be running into a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Jsf have h:panelGroup tag for render HTML DIV and SPAN

Comment: @0x5a4d: Wjhy use an `h:panelGroup` when a plain div is enough? Each jsf component you add that does not do anything is a little performance loss.

Comment: @Kukeltje  h:panelGroup have usful attributes like **rendered** and **binding**.

Comment: Yes, I know, that is why I stated  "when a plain div is enough". And ".. does not do anything...". When he/she NEEDS these attributes, using a panelgroup is good. Otherwise it is superfluous... (as it seems to be in  this case).

Comment: Of course, you can use the div tag in this case, but component will not be part of the JSF component tree (i.e. not available in the Java code). In addition to that, you will not be able to refresh it directly using Ajax (except, of course, if you do the refresh directly in some of your JavaScript code). But its not this case

Comment: @Kukeltje For `render` attribute.

Comment: you cannot re-'render' a div... You can only render jsf components. Then you should do like @0x5a4d says and use a h:panelGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. not recommend

```html
<h:form id="dialogForm" prependId="false">

</h:form>
```

```css
#dialogForm{
    background-color: red;
}
```

jsf generate id's like formId:component1Id:component2Id and prependId="false" off this behaviour for current form

2. recommended

```html
<h:form id="dialogForm" styleClass="formStyleClass">

</h:form>
```

```css
.formStyleClass{
    background-color: red;
}
```

> Do not place dialog inside tables, containers likes divs with relative positioning or with non-visible overflow defined, in cases like these functionality might be broken. This is not a limitation but a result of DOM model. For example dialog inside a layout unit, tabview, accordion are a couple of examples. Same applies to confirmDialog as well.

Comment: The prependId="false" is more then **not recommended**. When you start doing ajax, you'll be surprised that the 'prependId="false" does NOT work for ajax calls

Comment: Yes you'll right, _prependId="false"_ not a true way, just for clear example

Comment: And I fail to see the advantage of using a `styleClass` on the form instead of the `id` of the form.

Answer (score 0):

As far as it comes to `dialogForm`, Id attribute of generated html is different than its JSF representation. You can check out your html id attribute by clicking it and choosing *View Source*.